# IntersectionObserver is not triggered when div ref is conditionally rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, ref, intersection-observer

I'm trying to build infinite scroll pagination in React, and using JavaScript's IntersectionObserver to attach a load more div. Basically when the user scrolls down to the table then - `Loading...` text will come up and an API is being called to fetch the table contents from backend. The issue is If I show the `Loading...` text without any conditional rendering , then the IntersectionObserver is being properly triggered but when I add a condition to render the `Loading...` text then the IntersectionObserver is not being triggered at all.

From the backend API , I will be getting `numberOfPages` variable , which will define how many pages/ records present in db , in return `Loading...` text shouldn't come up after it reaches the last page. This is what I've tried so far. Also tried one of the blog i found out
[Blog Link](https://dev.to/hunterjsbit/react-infinite-scroll-in-few-lines-588f).

Codesandbox code : [Code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mahavira-w9sr5?file=/src/App.js)

Live : [Live demo here](https://w9sr5.csb.app/)

Comment: I suggest you use `react-intersection-observer`. It makes your life much easier

Comment: @jarivak, ok, I see. but in your codesandbox code, I see the loading text is always exist, and the observer is triggered everytime when I scroll down, so I don't get your problem

Comment: Yes loading text exists and to that text I've attached the ref,which will trigger the intersection api, but it is not triggering in my case ,you can check the console, for every trigger I've a console log registered.